# What is the equivalent of Brownie's (Pytest) "Contract.from_abi()" in Foundry test?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, brownie, foundry

There is a test that uses brownie (pytest) where it creates a new contract using two contracts' abi:

```
Contract.from_abi("mock", mock.address, Contract1.abi + Contract2.abi, owner=accounts[0])
```

Link to brownie docs: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=from_abi#Contract.from_abi

...this new "mock" contract is part of the set up and used throughout the tests...

I am trying to translate this in **Foundry** but I cannot seem to find the correct way... any one has any idea on how to tackle this?